# Fraction of group by column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe like the following :

```
     A     B    C 
0  foo    b1   25
1  foo    b2  400
2  foo    b3   75  
3  bar    b1  100
4  bar    b2  200
6  baz    b2  100
7  baz    b3  100
```

Say we want to build another dataframe that contains, for each group defined by `A`, the fraction of `C` each value of `B` represents.

That is, using the example above, the result would be:

```
     A     B          C 
0  foo    b1   0.050000
1  foo    b2   0.800000
2  foo    b3   0.150000 
3  bar    b1   0.333333
4  bar    b2   0.666667
6  baz    b2   0.500000
7  baz    b3   0.500000
```

To see why, note that for row `0`, we have `(25 + 400 + 75)/500 = 0.05`, etc.

---

### Attempts:

**Attempt 1:**

```
df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: x['C'].sum())
```

I end up with: `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

**Attempt 2:** When I try with `apply` I almost get what I need:

```
> df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['C']/x['C'].sum()).reset_index()

     A  level_1         C
0  bar        3  0.333333
1  bar        4  0.666667
2  baz        6  0.500000
3  baz        7  0.500000
4  foo        0  0.050000
5  foo        1  0.800000
6  foo        2  0.150000
```

the only thing missing is that the column `B` is "lost".

**Attempt 3:**  If I to assign the result of `apply` to a new column:

```
df['D'] = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['C']/x['C'].sum())
```

I get: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`.

---

What can I do to get exactly the output I need? This is all with Pandas 0.17 on Python 3.5.

Comment: How did you try the transform? It works for me...

Comment: just assign a new column to the transform, e.g. `df['C_pct'] = df.C / df.groupby("A")["C"].transform("sum")`

Comment: weirdly, even with `as_index=False` the apply version doesn't work... I kindof think perhaps it should work (modulo ordering)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation), which "puts back" the aggregated results:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("A")["C"].transform("sum")
Out[11]:
0    500
1    500
2    500
3    300
4    300
6    200
7    200
dtype: int64
```

and divide (and assign this column back to C):

```
In [12]: df["C"] / df.groupby("A")["C"].transform("sum")
Out[12]:
0    0.050000
1    0.800000
2    0.150000
3    0.333333
4    0.666667
6    0.500000
7    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Sorry, not sure if you saw the second part of my question. I tried using transform and apply without luck.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina seen them thanks, I hope this way works for you. Will have a little think if I can get this with an apply (but this will always be more efficient). :)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the response of @AndyHayden, just assign the result to a new column:

```
df['C_pct'] = df.C / df.groupby("A")["C"].transform("sum")

>>> df
     A   B    C     C_pct
0  foo  b1   25  0.050000
1  foo  b2  400  0.800000
2  foo  b3   75  0.150000
3  bar  b1  100  0.333333
4  bar  b2  200  0.666667
6  baz  b2  100  0.500000
7  baz  b3  100  0.500000
```

You could overwrite the original columns as well if you don't mind losing the original data:

```
df['C'] = ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this "extending"... but there you are.

Comment: Your response returns a series instead of attaching it to the original DF.  From the comments, it didn't seem like the issue was resolved, so I posted it to make it totally obvious.  I added a comment to the same effect about the same time you originally posted.